# Deklination von „Variable“

Tags: adjective, noun, nominalization, declension

Laut 8. Auflage von Duden 9 kann das Wort „Variable“ sowohl wie ein substantiviertes Adjektiv (Nominativ Plural: „zwei Variable“, siehe http://www.canoonet.eu/services/Controller?dispatch=inflection&input=Variable&features=%28Cat+N%29%28Gender+F%29&country=D&lookup=caseInSensitive) als auch wie ein Substantiv (Nominativ Plural: „zwei Variablen“) dekliniert werden. Korrekturen.de weichen dem Problem in http://www.korrekturen.de/flexion/deklination/Variable/ aus, und http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Variable listet beide Möglichkeiten auf.

***Gibt es einen Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen den beiden Deklinationsarten?*** Mich interessiert insbesondere die mathematisch-logisch-programmiersprachliche Verwendung. Zu Bedeutungsunterschieden sagt Duden 9 bei „Variable“ leider nichts. Unter http://blog.canoonet.eu/2013/06/24/zum-unterschied-zwischen-der-totale-und-der-illustrierten/ gibt's Beispiele mit Bedeutungsunterschieden bei Deklination ähnlicher Wörter, doch bei „Variable“ findet man weder eine Angabe eines Unterschiedes in der Bedeutung, noch, dass es keinen Unterschied gibt. Dudens „Die Deutsche Rechtschreibung“ in der 21. Auflage aus 1996 schreibt „**Va**|**ri**|̱**b**|**le** (↑R 130) die; -n, *Plur*. -n, *ohne Artikel fachspr. auch* - (*Math.* veränderliche Größe; *Ggs.* Konstante); zwei -[n];“. Im mathematischen Sinne einer veränderlichen Größe waren 1996 also immer noch beide Möglichkeiten für den Plural zumindest formal zugelassen :-(.

Das Substantiv „Variable“ hat an sich mindestens vier Bedeutungen, die sich teilweise überschneiden:

1. Logische Unbekannte eines logisch-mathematischen Terms, wie etwa in „Wenn , ,  ganze Zahlen,  und  ganzzahlige Variable sind, heißt ²+y+² eine binäre quadratische Form …“ (Edmund Landau, [Handbuch der Lehre von der Verteilung der Primzahlen](http://www.fuchs-braun.com/media/2092597b8e6814aeffff806afffffff1.pdf), 1909, Seite 536).
2. Bezeichnung eines Speicherbereichs eines zuweisungsorientierten Programms, wie etwa in „Variable x des Programms »x≔1; y≔x+1«“.
3. Formaler Parameter einer Funktionsvorschrift eines funktionalen Programms, wie etwa in „Variable x der Funktionsvorschrift »fun f(x:int) = if x<0 then -1 else if x>0 then 1 else 0 fi fi«“.
4. Allgemeine, veränderliche, nicht näher bestimmte Größe in der natürlichen Sprache („Das Team aus der Schweiz aber hat ein Gewichtsproblem – und der Mensch in der Maschine ist die größte Variable, um daran etwas zu ändern.“, siehe http://www.faz.net/aktuell/sport/formel-1/formel-1-die-fahrer-hungern-und-duersten-12880484.html).

Bei Edmund Landau sieht man die adjektivische Deklination, allerdings ohne Gewähr für die Allgmeingültigkeit, und die Sprache wandelte sich seitdem.

Vielleicht kann man es aus der „Veränderliche“ ableiten, aber da kenne ich mich noch weniger aus.

Comment: Eine gute Antwort - was ist die Frage? Die 4 Bedeutungen sind eigentlich die gleiche Bedeutung in 4 Kontexten und sie hängen nicht mit unterschiedlichen Pluralbildungen zusammen.

Comment: Puh, es gibt da einen Unterschied, aber der ist sehr schwer in Worte zu fasen. Bei Programmen würde ich als Informatik-Student immer von *Variable**n*** reden, genauso wenn es in der Mathematik um benannte Größen geht, aber von "Variable" eher sprechen, wenn es um (un-) benannte Größen geht. "Die Formel hat drei Variable" vs. "Die drei Variablen x,y,z [...]".

Comment: Für mich klingt das immer nach einer Ellipse für "Die Funktion hat drei variable Parameter".

Comment: @infinitezero Dann wäre der von Polygnome empfundene Bedeutungsunterschied tatsächlich nur der Unterschied der Deklination bei Adjektiven mit bzw. ohne vorangestellten bestimmten Artikel. Klingt plausibel.

Comment: @Just_A_Man: Eine Spielzeugauto, mit dem ein Kind spielt und ein Fortbewegungsmittel werden, auch wenn man sie sprachlich differenzieren kann und sie ganz unterschiedlich sind dennoch beide "Auto" genannt. ("Gib dem Peter doch auch mal das Auto!"/"Zum Bäcker nehmen wir mal nicht das Auto"). Sie basieren auf der selben Bedeutung. Nr. 4 ist einfach eine Metapher oder die Anwendung des math. Konzepts in der Analyse einer konkreten Angelegenheit, hier des Motorsports.

Comment: @Just_A_Man: Kein Wunder, dass Du zu Außerirdischen greifen musst und Dich nicht einfach bei Franzosen oder Engländern bedienen kannst - da funktioniert dieser Aspekt der Sprache nämlich wie bei uns, was zeigt, dass ich Recht habe. :)

Comment: @Just_A_Man: Dann nimm Schrauben. Es gibt Holzschrauben, die sich ins Holz und ähnliches hineinfressen und Maschinenschrauben, die genau in einer Mutter o.ä. passen. Außerdem gibt es Schiffsschrauben. Das basiert aber alles auf der Bewegung des Schraubens - im Ggs. zu Schimmel (weißes Pferd vs. Pilz).

Answer (score 1):

Der Begriff *Variable*, dessen Plural genauso heißt, ist dieses (4.) und auch (1.) der Fragestellung. Es ist als adjektivistisches Synonym zu "variable Größe" zu verstehen.

Die *Variable* mit Plural *Variablen* ist ein konkretes benanntes Objekt mit Wert beim Rechnen (also auch Programmieren).

Comment: "Variable Größe" ist aber Singular - wie verhält es sich denn mit dem Plural? Zu 4) "Die Mitglieder der Partei sind die größten Variable bei der Planung einer Strategie." Wenn man ausdrücken will, dass die nicht alle wie eine, zusammenfassende Variable modelliert werden können.

Comment: @Just_A_Man: Ich verstehe nicht, worauf Du hinauswillst und was für ein Problem mit Menge oder Reihe ähnlich ist. Du wolltest doch wissen, ob der mögliche Plural "Variable" die Bedeutung innerhalb der 4 Optionen auf eine echte Teilmenge einschränkt. Äöü antwortet, es sei ein Synonym zu "variable Größe". Im Plural also "variable Größen", nicht wahr? Kann man also sagen "Die Menschen in den Maschinen sind die größten Variable, um etwas zu ändern." Ich tendiere zu nein, würde aber wohl immer "Variablen" als Plural nutzen - kann also Ignoranz sein oder regionaler Usus.

Comment: @Just_A_Man: Bei (1.) war ich mir nicht ganz sicher, was du da meinst. Konkrete Objekte sind mit "n" im Plural...

Comment: @Just_A_Man: Und den Transfer zu "Manche/einige Mitglieder der Partei sind die größten Variable ..." bekommst Du nicht hin?

Comment: @Just_A_Man: Darauf will ich doch hinaus, dass es in den Fällen "Variablen" heißen muss - was ich allerdings nicht sicher sagen kann. Dann zählt (4) nicht, wie von Dir behauptet, zu den Fällen, in denen die Mehrzahl mit "Variable" gebildet wird. "Der Mensch IST die größte ..." ist eben kein Plural, "Die Menschen sind die größten ..." wäre Plural.

Comment: @Just_A_Man: Ja, ich bleibe bei meiner Aussage, denn dein Beispiel aus 1. ist inhaltlich letzten Endes inhaltlich dasselbe wie 4.

Answer (score 0):

Bei dem Zitat von 1909 würde derselbe Mathematiker den Plural "Variable" heute explizit als "Variablen" bezeichnen. Da liegen 100 Jahre Sprachentwicklung dazwischen. Die Programmierer und Mathematiker sehen es wahrscheinlich als Vorteil an, in dem noun/Term eine von diesen Dingern und eine Mehrzahl davon unterscheiden zu können.